# Javascript or jQuery replace text

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, replace

I need to replace some text that is on the page within the body tag. I am using javascript but have jquery available if needed. I basically need to replace test® (test with the registered trademark) with TEST® or tests® with TESTS® and it could even be test with TEST® or tests with TESTS®. I am able to uppercase them but its not liking to work for me with the ® sign, it wants to put duplicates on ones that already have it. Basically anything on the page that has the word test or tests should be TEST® or TESTS® if it is plural. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
So now I have this:

```
var html = $('body').html();
var html = html.replace(/realtor(s)?(&reg;)?/gi, function(m, s1, s2){
    var s = s1?s1.toUpperCase():"";
    var reg = s2?s2:'&reg;';
    return "REALTOR"+s+reg;
});
$('body').html(html);
```

Its working well other than it is duplicating the ® on the ones that already had them any ideas on how not to?

Comment: just google javascript text replace , first link comes up tizag.com thats quite enough to accomplish so , good point Pointy

Comment: The problem with using `&reg;` or any HTML escape code is that the browser translates it to the actual symbol. To get to that symbol using string functions, use "®" but if you are using match, replace, etc, you will have to use the unicode value "\u00ae". See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have already said, you will not be able to match the `&reg;`, you need to match on
`\u00ae`.

The code you provided needs to be changed to:

```
var html = $('body').html();
var html = html.replace(/realtor(s)?(\u00ae)?/gi, function(m, s1, s2){
    var s = s1?s1.toUpperCase():"";
    var reg = s2?s2:'&reg;';
    return "REALTOR"+s+reg;
});
$('body').html(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on jAndy's answer, try this:

```
 $("div, p, span").each(function(){
  o = $(this);
  o.html( o.text().replace(/test(|s)\u00ae/gi, function($1){
     return($1.toUpperCase());
  }));
 });
```

---

Using the code you provided, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('body').html( $('body').html().replace(/realtor(|s)\u00ae/gi, function($1){
  return($1.toUpperCase() );
 }));
})
```

Comment: that works great the only problem is that if there is no &reg; at the end (for example realtor) it doesnt add the &reg; in there. I need it to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: Gave you a plus one because you helped actually get the solution.

Comment: The way your question is written it seems that the &reg; is already there,  so this replace function will find all instances of realtor® or realtors® and make it uppercase, so you don't need to add another "®". Anyway, glad you have your solution and thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part here is to match the ®, which is a Unicode character, I guess...
Have you tried the obvious?

```
var newStr = str.replace(/test(s)?®?/gi, function(m, s1){
  var s = s1?s1.toUpperCase():"";
  return "TEST"+s+"®";
});
```

If the problem is that `®` does not match, try with its unicode character number:

```
/test(s)?\u00ae/
```

Sorry if the rest does not work, I assume your replacement already works and you just have to also match the ® so that it does not get duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating something from scratch try using an alternate library. I develop with PHP so using a library that has identical methods in JavaScript is a life saver.

[PHP.JS Library](http://phpjs.org/)

`var newReplaced = $P.str_replace("find","replace",varSearch);`

Comment: -1 (you just can't see it... cause I'm out of votes). Self promoting is always bad, but yours is terrible.

Comment: I use this library in conjunction with jQuery. No real problems.